# pandas aggregate data from two data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas data frames, with some indexes and some column names in common (like partially overlapping time-series related to common quantities).

I need to merge these two dataframes in a single one containing all the indexes and all the values for each index, keeping the values of the left (right) one in case an index-column combination appears in both data frames.

Both merge and join methods are unhelpful as the merge method will duplicate information I don't need and join causes the same problem.

What's an efficient method to obtain the result I need?

EDIT:
If for example I have the two data frames

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
'C1' : [1.1, 1.2, 1.3],
'C2' : [2.1, 2.2, 2.3],
'C3': [3.1, 3.2, 3.3]},
index=['a', 'b', 'c'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
'C3' : [3.1, 3.2, 33.3],
'C4' : [4.1, 4.2, 4.3]},
index=['b', 'c', 'd'])
```

What I need is a method that allows me to create:

```
merged = pd.DataFrame({
'C1': [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 'nan'],
'C2': [2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 'nan'],
'C3': [3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 33.3], 
'C4': ['nan', 4.1, 4.2, 4.3]},
index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

Comment: Show us some data and/or code.

Answer (score 3):

Here are three possibilities:

- Use `concat/groupby`: First concatenate both DataFrames vertically. Then group by the index and select the first row in each group.
- Use `combine_first`: Make a new index which is the union of `df1` and `df2`. Reindex `df1` using the new index. Then use `combine_first` to fill in NaNs with values from `df2`.
- Use manual construction: We could use `df2.index.difference(df1.index)` to find exactly which rows need to be added to `df1`. So we could manually select those rows from `df2` and concatenate them on to `df1`.

For small DataFrames, `using_concat` is faster. For larger DataFrames, `using_combine_first` appears to be slightly faster than the other options:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import perfplot

def make_dfs(N):
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(N,2)))
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(N,2)), index=range(N//2,N//2 + N))
    return df1, df2

def using_concat(dfs):
    df1, df2 = dfs
    result = pd.concat([df1,df2], sort=False)
    n = result.index.nlevels
    return result.groupby(level=range(n)).first()

def using_combine_first(dfs):
    df1, df2 = dfs
    index = df1.index.union(df2.index)
    result = df1.reindex(index)
    result = result.combine_first(df2)
    return result

def using_manual_construction(dfs):
    df1, df2 = dfs
    index = df2.index.difference(df1.index)
    cols = df2.columns.difference(df1.columns)
    result = pd.concat([df1, df2.loc[index]], sort=False)
    result.loc[df2.index, cols] = df2
    return result

perfplot.show(
    setup=make_dfs,
    kernels=[using_concat, using_combine_first, 
             using_manual_construction],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(5,21)],
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    xlabel='len(df)')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code I can only give a generic answer:

To merge 2 dataframes use

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='right', on=('col1', 'col2'))
```

or

```
a.merge(b, how='right', on=('c1', 'c2'))
```